# WordPress Almacenamiento de una Imagen, PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Hola este campo almacena información, necesito obtener "2020/04/matematicas.png" que código php podría usar

```
a:5:{s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:4:"file";s:23:"2020/04/matematicas.png";s:5:"sizes";a:0:{}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

El campo está serializado ( no es json ), en php podés usar [`unserialize( string $str [, array $options ] ) : mixed`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php), aunque si te mantenés dentro del ecosistema wordpres ( código para un theme o plugin ) tenés una función mas "segura" llamada [`maybe_unserialize( string $original )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) que verifica si lo que le pasas está serializado.

```
<?php
        $options ='a:5:{s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:4:"file";s:23:"2020/04/matematicas.png";s:5:"sizes";a:0:{}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}';

        var_dump( unserialize($options) );
```

---

resultado:

```
array(5) {
  ["width"]=>
  int(100)
  ["height"]=>
  int(100)
  ["file"]=>
  string(23) "2020/04/matematicas.png"
  ["sizes"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["image_meta"]=>
  array(12) {
    ["aperture"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["credit"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["camera"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["caption"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["created_timestamp"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["copyright"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["focal_length"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["iso"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["shutter_speed"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["title"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["orientation"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["keywords"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```